# Importing text and images swift Map Kit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, assets

I am trying to get specific images and text files to imbed into my second view controller based on which pin is selected in my Map View. Currently I have my title being transferred through a segue. my thought was to name the text files and images the same as the title so they would be correctly selected when the title was found.

EG: Title = big ben : title = "big ben" hence select image title.png and title.txt
However I am having trouble implementing this as I am unsure how to tell swift to select an image and text file from the assets folder.

I currently have the segue and prepare for segue implemented as:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        if let artworkPin = view.annotation as? Artwork {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "no", sender: artworkPin)
        }
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "no" {
            if let artworkPin = sender as? Artwork {
                let ViewTwo = segue.destination as! ViewTwo
                ViewTwo.artworkPin = artworkPin
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

and my second view class as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var art_image: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var art_desc: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var art_title: UILabel!
var artworkPin: Artwork!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    art_title.text = artworkPin.title




}
```

how can I get swift to pull from the assets folder?
I have attached my full code below:
[ViewControllerOne](http://pastebin.com/S2Ux8Sy6)

[ViewTwo](http://pastebin.com/qb2pB1mh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when storing non image files in XCAssets, you should use NSDataAsset to acccess their content

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSDataAsset_Class/

```
 func readBundle(file:String) -> String
{
    var res = ""
    if let asset = NSDataAsset(name: file) , let string = String(data:asset.data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8){
        res = string
    }
    return res
}
```

To load the image in second view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var art_image: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var art_desc: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var art_title: UILabel!
var artworkPin: Artwork!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    art_title.text = readBundle(artworkPin.title)
art_image.image = UIImage(named:"PinSample")

}
```

**Note** : Asset image name and name in the code should be same

Comment: I have an unresolved identifier error with readBundle is that part of a module I need to import? Also do i have to present it as named:"String" could I do named:title so whatever the title is (that being the imported text for art_title.text) it opens a file named that title. Otherwise if I had say "Pin 1" no matter what title and pin is clicked on the image of Pin 1 would be loaded. If this doesn't make sense to you let me know and I will try to explain again.

Comment: You can use the title as image name , if both are same

Comment: Is there a way to do multiple images in a image view? Without animation just with navigation controls like the three bubbles provided with google maps?

Comment: try image view with page control

Comment: ah I see would I be able to reference `named:"folder"` to a folder and have the images be collected from there?